# Geneology of survivors in a critical discrete Galton-Watson process

Tags: pr.probability

Hello. After flipping through a few textbooks on birth-death processes, I can't seem to find anything about genealogical distribution of survivors (conditioned on non-extinction). What I am looking for is a statement roughly of the type, "in generation n, there is probability at least P(j,k,n) that descendants have survived from at least k distinct members of generation j".

I'm interested in the critical case of the Galton-Watson process, where the number of descendents is i.i.d. with mean 1. If necessary, assume the distribution is Bin(r,1/r).

Also, my sample question about P(j,k,n) is just the easiest thing I could think to write down. But I would like to know how likely it is for there to exist a very uniformly distributed subpopulation of size roughly n in generation n.

Comment: "ancestors have survived from at least k distinct members of generation j". What exactly do you mean by this? Should "ancestors" really be "descendants" in this phrase?

Comment: Yes, I meant "descendants" there. I will edit the post now.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at
**Elementary New Proofs of Classical Limit Theorems for Galton-Watson Processes** by Jochen Geiger, *Journal of Applied Probability*, Vol. 36, No. 2 (1999), pp. 301-309.  It looks to me like the construction there could be helpful to you.